# Managing Credentials in Azure .NET Core 2.0 SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication

I'm a little bit lost on how you can create credentials in the Azure .NET SDK without having to call the credentials from a local file.

In my case, I have a few subscriptions and I'm storing my data in a local database. I want to make multiple calls to Azure for my VMs using the credentials I store in the database.

They have numerous classes representing ways to authenticate in the [SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory?view=azure-dotnet), but I can't see a clear way to create access tokens or use credentials (tenant id, subscription id, client id and secret) through the SDK.

For example, when calling one of the Client classes ([ComputeManagementClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn620741.aspx)) you can call it with credentials to authenticate the request to Azure but they don't seem to provide a Class to generate the credentials beyond [from a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp#create-credentials)).

Does anyone have an MSDN reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to [AzureCredentialsFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory?view=azure-dotnet) class, we could know that we also could get the credentials [FromServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromserviceprincipal?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_Authentication_AzureCredentialsFactory_FromServicePrincipal_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_AzureEnvironment_) or  [FromUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromuser?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_Authentication_AzureCredentialsFactory_FromUser_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_AzureEnvironment_). In your case I recomment that use the [FromServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromserviceprincipal?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_Authentication_AzureCredentialsFactory_FromServicePrincipal_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_AzureEnvironment_) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) to operate the Azure resource.  I also do a demo for that.

**Note**: How to registry Azure AD Application and assign role please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

```
var clientId = "clientId";
var secretKey = "secretKey";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, secretKey, tenantId,AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
var result = client.VirtualMachines.ListAllAsync().Result;
```

[image]

Comment: I actually was just answering the question myself with this exact answer. Thank you for beating me to it!

Comment: I should note, the ComputeManagementCLient is also legacy (Azure Classic) its recommend to use the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fliuent.Azure` method for establishing a connection to Azure using ARM.